# Foglight for oracle custom reports generation for every n secs

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle foglight monitoring tool,

I did the following steps

Installed foglight for oracle -> and then oracle db(10g) -> and I created an instance of orcle -> Now fogLight tool displaying the lot of metrics -> and I created a custom reports in **My Dashboards**

I succeed up to the above step, but my requirement is that

I want that custom report to run for every **n secs** , and that reports should be saved in any **directory** or to be directly accessible through **HTTP** request (It is help full me to, if i get through HTTP request (using program)).

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far to fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Thanks scott,I need to get the reports generated by the foglight tool for oracle , for this i done above mentioned steps. when i run the custom reports manually in foglight tool it is generating reports as (PDF or XML) file ,and i downloaded it to my local drive and i am using it. but it should be done automatically(generation and download) for every n secs , how can i get this

Comment: Sounds like you just need to make a script. If you can perform the actions you want from the command line, it is a good candidate for scripting.